# How to merge 2 websites into 1 website with 2 stores

Tags: magento2, database, multi-website, multidomain

I have 2 Magento websites (Web A and Web B with different Magento installations) but I need a single Magento installation with 2 websites how to merge 2 different websites to a single installation with multi-website.

## Present structure

**Web A -> database A**

products= 125

customers = 2000

orders = 4677

**Web B -> Database B**

products = 543

customers= 24590

orders = 67090

## now I need

**Web A, Web B -> database**

two Databases into single database same links like customers order and products all data

how to merge this data is there any efficient way

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: already added most info present i have 2 websites with different Magento installations now i need to merge 2 websites with single magento installation